# android:errorMessageBackground getting no resource found error in styles.xml

Tags: android, android-widget, android-edittext

i was working on `EditText`  validations and using '`setError`' to show error messages.

My primary motto is to change the error popup as par my application design. I used the `"android:errorMessageBackground"` in styles but unfortunately i am getting `**No Resource found error**`.

Used Base API: `2.2` (Even tried with `4.0.3` also) not sure what we need to do ?

Answer (score 3):

This seems to be a known issue: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=55879