# Android - Changing background color of EditText's setError popup message

Tags: java, android

I want to change the background color of the EditText's setError pop up message to white. I have changed the text color to green as shown in the image. But not being able to change the background color. Code written below:

```
if (TextUtils.isEmpty(editTextUsername)){
 txt_L_user_ID.setError(Html.fromHtml("<font color=green>User ID could not be empty</font>"));
                }
```

Below is the image.

[image: Please click to see image.]

Comment: First, do NOT spam with irrelevant tags. 2nd - this is not standard widget. Check its docs

Comment: try https://github.com/sherifelkhatib/WidgyWidgets

Comment: try this [one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14127710/change-background-of-edittexts-error-message)

Comment: @Stephen I'm sorry but this is not what I want..just want to change the color of the background from black to white.

Comment: @SarthakSharma http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14413575/how-to-write-style-to-error-text-of-edittext-in-android . Check that

Comment: @SarthakSharma any success in achieving this?

Comment: @Safeer  yes it worked. Sorry for replying so much late.