# How to customize setError message in Android Studio with Java

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I have several error messages in an Android Studio app using Java and I cannot figure out how to customize their appearance. I have consulted several answers on this site but none of them have worked for what I want.

This is what the error message looks like.

[image: Error message.]

I want to change the colors of the black background, the white text, and the red line and icon.

This is the code for the error message,

```
String email = editTextEmail.getText().toString().trim();
        String password = editTextPassword.getText().toString().trim();

        if(email.isEmpty()){
            editTextEmail.setError("Please enter an email.");
            editTextEmail.requestFocus();
            return;
        }
```

and this is the code for the editText object.

```
<EditText
            android:id="@+id/login_email"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="8dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:hint="Email"
            android:padding="8dp"
            android:drawableLeft="@drawable/email_icon"
            android:textColor="#417577"
            android:textSize="25dp" />
```

How do I change the colors displayed in the error message? Also, is there a way to set these color changes for the whole app and not just individually?

Thank you!

Comment: Refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14127710/change-background-of-edittexts-error-message), looks like the same question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After googling little bit I found some answers for you. Here I am implementing those sites.

1. [devdeeds](https://devdeeds.com/change-color-seterror-method/) [git repo](https://github.com/jayakrishnan-pm/CustomSetError)
2. [findnerd](http://findnerd.com/list/view/Trick-to-change-text-color-inside-setError-method-of-EditText/12741/)
3. [xspdf](https://www.xspdf.com/help/51775218.html)

I am implementing that source code which looks like good for me

It is easy way to change color. If you have idea of `html` than you might see here you are just changing color by html format.

```
editText.setError(Html.fromHtml("<font color="#000000">"error!"</font>"));
```

Following source code used in java

```
int errorColor;
    final int version = Build.VERSION.SDK_INT;
    if (version >= 23) {

         errorColor = ContextCompat.getColor(getApplicationContext(), R.color.errorColor);
    } else {
         errorColor = getResources().getColor(R.color.errorColor);
    }


    String errorString = "This field cannot be empty";  // your error message
    ForegroundColorSpan foregroundColorSpan = new ForegroundColorSpan(errorColor);
    SpannableStringBuilder spannableStringBuilder = new SpannableStringBuilder(errorString);
    spannableStringBuilder.setSpan(foregroundColorSpan, 0, errorString.length(), 0);
    editTextView.setError(spannableStringBuilder);
```